# Can you implement Binary Search Tree in Haskell with O(log n) insertion?

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

If I understand correctly, modifying (insertion or deletion) a **Binary Search Tree** in ***Haskell*** requires copying the whole tree, so practically making it being **O(n)**. Is there a way to implement it in **O(log n)** or maybe compiler would optimize **O(n)** insertion down to **O(log n)** "under the hood"?

Comment: What makes you think you need to copy the whole tree? For trees *in general*, you only need to copy the path to the node you insert / delete, which is O(log n). Does your BST have some other restrictions that make this impossible?

Comment: **Yes**, you can insert in *O(log n)*. Since all data is immutable, you can reuse the nodes in the original tree, and thus only update a path with size *O(log n)*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag No, I have no specific tree cases - just the question on BST in general. I guess I need to ponder on thinking about insert / delete as a path. If so, question must be restated as *insertion is both time **O(log n)** and space **O(log n)**?* while in imperative language it would be *time **O(log n)** and pace **O(1)**?*.

Comment: Only if you want the tree to be *persistent*, i.e. you want to keep *both the old and the new version of the tree*. If you don't want that, then you can just throw away the old nodes and only need O(1) space. If you *do* want to keep both versions, then your *additional space* required to keep the old version is O(log n) – and note that this is something you cannot do with a mutable tree in an imperative language at all, without fully copying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, modifying (insertion or deletion) a Binary Search Tree in Haskell requires copying the whole tree, so practically making it being *O(n)*.

You do not need to copy the entire tree. Indeed, let us work with a simple *unbalanced* binary search tree, like:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Empty deriving (Eq, Show)
```

then we can insert a value with:

```
insertIn :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insertIn x = go
  where go Empty = Node Empty x Empty
        go n@(Node l v r)
          | x < v = Node (go l) v r
          | x > v = Node l v (go r)
          | otherwise = n
```

Here we *reuse* `r` in case we construct a `Node (go l) v r`, and we *reuse* `l` in case we construct a `Node l v (go r)`. For each node we visit, we create a new node where one of the two subtrees is used in the new node. This means that the new tree will point to the *same* subtree objects as the original tree.

In this example, the amount of new nodes thus scales with *O(d)* with *d* the depth of the tree. If the tree is fairly balanced, than it will insert in *O(log n)*.

Of course you can improve the algorithm and define an AVL tree or red-black tree by storing more information in the node regarding balancing, in that case you thus can guarantee *O(log n)* insertion time.

The fact that all data is immutable here helps to reuse parts of the tree: we know that `l` and `r` can not change, so the two trees will share a large amount of nodes and thus reduce the amount of memory necessary if you want to use both the original and the new tree.

If there is no reference to the old tree necessary, the garbage collector will eventually collect the "old" nodes that have been replaced by the new tree.